# Cómo evitar el “Se detuvo la Aplicación”

Tags: android

quisiera saber cómo evitar usando el celular físico que salga el “Se detuvo la aplicación” apesar que algo haya estado mal en el código y en ves de eso que me muestre un mensaje con el error en el mismo celular.
Yo se que puedo ver el error en el “Error” del la ventana inferior del Android Studio, pero quisiera saber qué pasó cuando esté lejos de mi computadora y esté probando la app.
Gracias :)

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste usar un `try` y `catch` que englobe todo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para hacer eso necesitas hacer un `try catch` donde vas a colocar todo el código que crees que se va a generar un error. Por ejemplo:

```
try {
      Aquí va el código a evaluar....
} catch (Exception e) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Se generó un error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Esta sería una forma en la que podrías recoger el error y mostrarlo. Te recomiendo checar alguna página para que revises los Exceptios para cada tipo de error, así podrás escoger uno adecuado para tu situación.

Comment: Gracias, si funciono :)

Comment: De nada mi estimado

Comment: **Esto no sirve en realidad que se cierre la aplicación, lo que puedes provocar es que en otro punto deje de funcionar, ¿agregarías esto en todos los métodos de tu aplicación?** :-0